# append method in jquery is only showing the last element added

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add data to a table from a json request. Whatever I seem to try I can't get more than one table row to show. Any help would be appreciated.[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emeyqu40/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h2>Table</h2>
    <table class="table" id="products-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ASIN</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>MPN</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var prodAry = [1, 2, 3];
// create elements for table
var $tr = $('<tr>');
var $asin = $('<td>');
var $title = $('<td>');
var $price = $('<td>');
var $mpn = $('<td>');

prodAry.forEach(function(product, i) {
    var $newAsin = $asin.text(i);
    var $newTitle = $title.text(i);
    var $newPrice = $price.text(i);
    var $newMpn = $mpn.text(i);
    var $newTr = $tr.append($newAsin, $newTitle, $newPrice, $newMpn);
    $('#products-table > tbody:last-child').append($newTr);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you current implementation you are continuously appending the same `$tr` element.

You should create element inside the `forEach` loop.

```
var prodAry = [1, 2, 3];
prodAry.forEach(function(product, i) {
    // create elements for table
    var $tr = $('<tr>');
    var $asin = $('<td>');
    var $title = $('<td>');
    var $price = $('<td>');
    var $mpn = $('<td>');

    var $newAsin = $asin.text(i);
    var $newTitle = $title.text(i);
    var $newPrice = $price.text(i);
    var $newMpn = $mpn.text(i);
    var $newTr = $tr.append($newAsin, $newTitle, $newPrice, $newMpn);
    $('#products-table > tbody:last-child').append($newTr);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6afnkq7k/)

Comment: That did it! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($newTr[i]);
```

Add this after line 15 and you'll see the issue.